# Postgres value '' single quote vs NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

May I know what is different between `''` and `NULL` in Postgres?

My column type is set to `character varying (255)`

In my table the column field is set to '' and NULL.

The record is as below:

```
|Name |Mobile|
|James| ''   |
|John |      |
```

But when I select with query:

1. `Select Name from user where Mobile ='';`
2. `Select Name from user where Mobile is null;`

both are returning me different result.

Appreciate if anyone able to help and assist on this matter.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, an empty string `''` is something different than a `NULL` value in Postgres and pretty much every DBMS except Oracle.

Comment: `NULL` means "unknown". Empty string is still a string. You know what it is and its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `NULL` is used to represent missing values
- `''` is a value that corresponds to a empty string

I recommend adding `\pset null '(null)'` on your `.psqlrc`. Then,

```
SELECT Name, Mobile from user
```

will return

```
|Name |Mobile|
|James|      |
|John |(null)|
```

It makes easier to distinguish empty strings and missing values when using postgres on command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't even do:

```
Select Name from user where Mobile = null
```

Because NULL is not "equal to" NULL. (The null value represents an unknown value, and it is not known whether two unknown values are equal.) This behavior conforms to the SQL standard.

[Source](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html)